# How to search MongoDB data like JSON

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

(Using Python and pymongo)

Say I have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
"_id": {whatever},
"list of stuff" : ["entry1","entry2","entry3"],
"some number" : 12
```

How can I search the database and just get values from the entries? Whenever I do,

```
.find({"some number" : {"$exists : True}})
```

It still just gets the entire thing, (because I'm just checking if it has that key I think?) but I want to retrieve the value from "some number" to use. Like you would in JSON with `Object["some number"]`. How can I do this with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use projection to specify the fields you wish to keep in the result set. This example excludes `_id` and `list of stuff`.

```py
coll.find({"some number": {"$exists": True}},
          projection={"_id": False, "list of stuff": False})
```

The projection kwarg is [documented](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) with the `find` method